# c# windows service - not quite the intervals

Tags: c#, windows, service, intervals

```
    private const int intervalTime = 5;



    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
    }
    public long DoSomething()
    {
        intervalStopWatch.Reset();
        intervalStopWatch.Start();
        facade.Execute();
        intervalStopWatch.Stop();
        return intervalStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
```

Hi, I'd like to create service with something  similar to intervals, but my purpose is to count execution time of function "DoSomething" and if this time is >= intervalTime recall this function, if not ,wait until it passes interval time and then call the function. What is the best practise to do this?  And really don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look into [quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), seems like exactly what you need